# NOSQL database are good for these kind of filters?

Tags: database, nosql

I need two "lists" something like:

```
A
(date - price)
01-01-2012   100
02-01-2012   200
03-01-2012   300
04-01-2012   150

B
(date - price)
01-01-2012   10.5
02-01-2012   20.4
04-01-2012   25.3
05-01-2012   21.6
```

as you can see two simple lists with date and prices.
No, I would like to understand if I can use a NOsql database for this kind of filter:

I need to get all the prices (and the respective date) of the two lists, ONLY if they exists (in both lists). The result should be:

```
date A(price) B(price)
01-01-2012 - 100 - 10.5
02-01-2012 - 200 - 20.4
04-01-2012 - 150 - 25.3
```

Can I do it with a nosql db? These filters are good or are not recommended with this type of DB?

Thanks!

Comment: This task is trivial for any SQL DB. Use right tool for the job.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I know is trivial for any SQL DB, but I need to know if can I do the same thing with a NOsql DATABASE, is this possible? (performance decreases respect a SQL db regarding this kind of "query" ?)

Comment: "If you put your mind to it, you can accomplish everything". I can see how this can be done with Redis, for example. But I still would use an sql database for this.

Comment: Yes, it is possible for some NoSQL datatabases.  But since there is a large variety of NoSQL databases, you would get a better answer if you specify what kind of NoSQL database you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

The article can be a start for your needs
http://tebros.com/2011/07/using-mongodb-mapreduce-to-join-2-collections/.